# $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ if $f|_A$ is a bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let be $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a function and let be $A,B\subseteq X$: if the restriction $f|_A$ to $A$ is a bijection is it $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$? Unfortunately if $B\not\subseteq A$ I suppose that it is false: if this it is true could someone take to me a counterexample?

Comment: What do you mean by $f \mid_A$ is a bijection? That $f \mid_ A : A \to Y$ is a bijection or that $f \mid_ A : A \to f(A)$ is one?

Comment: $f|_A:A\rightarrow Y$ is a bijection.

Comment: $f(A \cap B)=f(A) \cap f(B)$ if $f$ is injective on $A \cup B$. Even knowing it is injective on $A$ and $B$ each considered separately is no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb R \to [0,\infty), f(x) = x^2$. Then for $A = [0,\infty)$ we get a bijection $f \mid_{[0,\infty)} : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$. Now take $B = (-\infty,0]$. Then $A \cap B = \{0\}$, thus $f(A \cap B) = \{f(0)\} = \{0\}$, but $f(A) \cap f(B) = [0,\infty)$.

Comment: You get a slightly more dramatic example if you trim off $0$, in which case $f(A \cap B)=\emptyset$ and $f(A) \cap f(B)=(0,\infty)$. I think this maybe demonstrates the point a little better: even if $f$ is injective on $A$ and $B$ each considered separately, if $f$ is hitting the same values on $A$ as it is hitting on $B$ then you can reach $f(A) \cap f(B)$ from points outside $A \cap B$.